# concatenate multiple files into single one but skip to reappend the already existing content

Tags: python

I have the following files with the following content ( one line per file:

> <189>162: CSR-1000V: *Sep 27 06:17:02: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line
>   protocol on Interface Loopback317, changed state to up <189>165:
>   CSR-1000V: *Sep 27 06:17:07: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on
>   Interface Loopback320, changed state to up <189>164: CSR-1000V: *Sep
>   27 06:17:06: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface
>   Loopback319, changed state to up <189>161: CSR-1000V: *Sep 27
>   06:16:59: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loopback316,
>   changed state to up<189>163: CSR-1000V: *Sep 27 06:17:04:
>   %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loop

I want to create a python script that can add those to a single file ( output.txt ), but i am stuck, since i am using for loop and the script keeps add the existing lines over and over

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: show us your code

Comment: !/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
subprocess.call('cd /home/adrian/from_hdfs; for f in *; do (cat "${f}"; echo) >> finalfile.txt; done', shell=True)

Comment: So you want to append or replace the lines into the existing file?

Comment: Finalfile.txt should be created, then for each new file that contains a new line, this line should be append to the finalfile.txt file, without re adding the existing lines from existing files

Comment: So you only want to add the new lines from your log file?

Comment: Yes :) New file with new line comes into the folder => append this new line to the finaltext. If this new line already exist in the finalfile file, then skip it. and so on for any other incoming files

Answer (score 0):

[Flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2y83.png)
As you can see in the attachment, there is a datapipeline in apache nifi, with the "ExecuteScript" Processor, where i run the above python code. The problem as i described is that existing lines from files are keep added continuously

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one methods this can be handled, but it depends your enviroment:

**First one:** Read through the files in the directory and append the data to your output file. Then, you save your already-read-files in a dictionary and save that on the disc, using pickle or json. Next time your code getc called, parse that list and skip the files you saved in that list. (PS: Use Python for file handling, its *the* use case)

**Second one:** [Pass the newly create files as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022775/how-to-handle-new-files-to-process-in-cron-job), if its suitable for you (I don't know anything about apache-nifi)

**Third one:** Compare the lines with the lines in your output file, but that will cost much performance and could be very unreliable.

**Fourth one:** Move the already read files into a subdirectory.

I would chose method one, as it's quite simple and straight forward.

edit:
I made a piece code (did not test it), if it doesn't work out of the box it should be clear what to do anyway.

```
import json
import os

directory = "/home/adrian/from_hdfs/"

parsed = {}
with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    parsed = json.load(json_file)


#open output file
with open("finalfile.txt", "a") as outfile:

    #loop through src directory
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename in parsed: 
            continue # skip file if already read

        file_abs = os.path.join(directory, filename)

        #print("Reading file: "+file_abs)
        with open(file_abs, "r") as src_file:
            myfile.write(src_file.read()) #append data from src to dest
            parsed[filename] = 1



with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(parsed, fp)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a sample code and then i will adjust for my env?

Answer (score 0):

```
#CODE:

#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import json
import os


subprocess.call('cd /home/adrian/from_hdfs; for f in *; do (cat "${f}"; echo) >> notfinal.txt; done', shell=True) =====> I am using this to generate "data.txt" from your example

directory = "/home/adrian/from_hdfs/"

parsed = {}
with open('/home/adrian/from_hdfs/notfinal.txt') as json_file:
    parsed = json.load(json_file)


#open output file
with open("finalfile.txt", "a") as outfile:

    #loop through src directory
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename in parsed: 
            continue # skip file if already read

        file_abs = os.path.join(directory, filename)

        #print("Reading file: "+file_abs)
        with open(file_abs, "r") as src_file:
            myfile.write(src_file.read()) #append data from src to dest
            parsed[filename] = 1



with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(parsed, fp)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 14, in <module>
    parsed = json.load(json_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```